# Rename [machines] to [transducer-machines]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Just [machines](/questions/tagged/machines) is too general and people will probably mistakenly use the tag for non-related things.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, calling a fairly specialized tag with such a generic name is calling for it to become overloaded with unrelated use. Since there are only 5 questions, I went and renamed the tag.

The tag wiki needs review by someone familiar with the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about it but its wiki says:

> "Machines" is a new functional programming concept that is an alternative to pipe libraries such as "pipes" "conduit". Some of its advantages includes more flexible input, allowing for example one component to read multiple inputs in various ways.

Comment: See also [the Haskell library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines) that implements the idea. There they use the name "transducers".